# How to use spread operator or use prev state in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I press a button it should call a function and send data. I am using spread operator so that I can keep the prev data. The problem is that my starting state is {} and when I console.log the data I see that I have empty object in my data

```
const [prevState, setState] = React.useState({});


const handleBtnPress =(info)=>{
setState(prevState => [...prevState, info] );

}

console.log(prevState)
```

output:

```
[{}, 'some data', 'for each button press']
```

output I am hoping for

```
['some data', 'for each button press']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial state should be an array. Change `{}` to `[]`

```
const [prevState, setState] = React.useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using using an `object` as initial state. And your expected output is an `Array`. Hence you should set initial state to an `Array`. Your code should be :

```
const [prevState, setState] = React.useState([]);
```